# "No such file of directory" for uploaded file

Tags: python, django, django-models

I try to get screenlist for video automatically when I upload it. But when I create a Video instance, I get:

```
OSError at /admin/videos/video/add/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out why I get this error because the file is in there.

Here's model:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='videos/videos')
    screenlist = models.ImageField(upload_to='videos/screenlists', editable=False)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None,
             update_fields=None):
        if self.pk is None:
            self.file.save(self.file.name, self.file, save=False)
            screenlist_path = get_screenlist(self.file.path.encode('utf-8'))
            self.screenlist = File(open(screenlist_path))

            video_info = get_video_info(self.file)
            self.duration = get_duration(video_info)
        super(Video, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
```

Here is string in get_screenlist method where the exception occurs:

```
info = subprocess.check_output([
        'ffprobe', '-loglevel', 'error', '-show_format',
        '-show_streams', path,  '-print_format', 'json'],
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
    )
```

Comment: Can you figure out what the exact directory couldn't be found? Path variable?

Comment: Yes, and when I use the same path for function get_screenlist in django shell (not inside save method), everything works fine.

Comment: Output the value of the path variable. It's probably incorrect.

Comment: Which function raise that exception?

Comment: @AndreyNelubin, `get_screenlist`, the exception is raised in the line, where I call `ffprobe`, it's in the question.

Comment: @sergzach, here's how it looks like: `/home/dmitry/coding/django_media/videoapp/videos/videos/hey_12.mp4`. And this file exists.

Comment: So, we figure out that the path is /home/... in the place of exception. Are you sure that your Python script (calling of `ffprobe`) has OS rights to read/change the file hey_12.mp4?

Comment: @sergzach, yeah, I've tried function `get_screenlist` outside of the `save` method and it worked. So I guess it's not a problem with permissions.

Comment: So, the file does not exist when executing the **save()** method, it creates later.

Comment: @sergzach, no. When the subprocess.check_output is called, it is already there. It's done with this line:`self.file.save(self.file.name, self.file, save=False)` in save method.

Answer (score 0):

**The 1st possible reason**

The file exists, but still locked by a parent process which has been created the file or opened it and has a lock for this file (BTW you use **subprocess.check_output()**).

You should release the lock before your further actions with the file.

**The 2nd possible reason**

Try to change **save=False** to **save=True** in the line:

```
self.file.save(self.file.name, self.file, save=False)
```

Comment: `save=True` is there on purpose. Without it this thing will call itself recursively and it will never stop uploading copies of the file to the media directory. Can't say anything about lock, I'll think about it, thank you.

Comment: @DmitryMikhaylov Any way it's better to call an external utility in a deferred task. Using Celery for example. I'm sure you have not a such problem if you use deferred tasks for things like this.